# periodic task using celery to delete a queryset result

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, periodic-task

I'm trying to execute a periodic task using celery to delete users who didn't activate their account in time. The screenshot bellow shows that the task is correctly discovered and executed, but when i check the database no changes are done.

The celery task :

```
#tasks.py
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from .utils import unconfirmed_users_delete

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

# A periodic task that will run every minute (the symbol "*" means every)
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(hour="*", minute="*", day_of_week="*")))
def delete_unconfirmed_users():
    return unconfirmed_users_delete()
```

The queryset to execute (checked in django shell and correctly working) :

```
#utils.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

def unconfirmed_users_delete():
    return User.objects.filter(is_active=False).filter(profile__key_expires__lt=timezone.now()).delete()
```

The task is correctly called every minute :

[image]

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a worker running along side your celery beat process?

Comment: @schillingt : Yes i have one, but made some changes to the task and utils files and forgot to restart it.
Please write your comment as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As @schillingt mentioned most of the time, we forget to (re)start worker process for the periodic task.

This happens because we have a beat scheduler which schedules the task and worker which executes the task.

```
celery -A my_task beat  # schedule tasks
celery worker -A my_task -l info  # consume tasks
```

A much better solution is to have a worker which schedules task & executes. You can do that using

```
celery worker -A my_task -l info --beat  # schedule & consume tasks
```

This schedules the periodic task and consumes it.

Comment: Can the worker can trigger scheduled tasks if it's currently executing a task itself? If not, then whilst probably fine for development-time, this approach probably shouldn't b recommended for production. I'm curious to know.

Comment: @dwightgunning I also tend to avoid this approach because normally the scheduling of the task is quite important for a business process and overload the worker with others task could create issues in precise scheduling.